# python sort list of strings using regex with varying number of pattern matches

Tags: python, string, sorting

Just starting to work on python and having difficulties sorting string list by multiple/varying number of matches.  Basically, given a list of strings, I need to split each string by a given regex (user provided) then sort by given list of keys (locations).  The key can either be single integer or a list in the order in which they should be sorted.  For example:

regex = r'.*(FF|TT|SS)_([-.\d]+v)_([-.\d]+c)_(FF|TT|SS).*'

key = [2,1,3]

Would sort the list of strings by location2, location1, location3.

I have the following that works for a fixed number of locations/keys, but can't figure out how to get it to work of varying number of 'keys':

```
import re

strlist = ["synopsys_SS_2v_-40c_SS.lib","synopsys_SS_1v_-40c_SS.lib","synopsys_SS_2v_-40c_TT.lib","synopsys_FF_3v_-40c_FF.lib", "synopsys_TT_4v_125c_TT.lib", "synopsys_TT_1v_-40c_TT.lib"]
regex = r'.*(FF|TT|SS)_([-\.\d]+v)_([-\.\d]+c)_(FF|TT|SS).*'
key = [2,1,3]

sfids_single = sorted(strlist, key=lambda name: ( 
  re.findall(regex,name)[0][key[0]], 
  re.findall(regex,name)[0][key[1]],
  re.findall(regex,name)[0][key[2]]))
```

Tried the following but it does not seem to work:

```
fids_single = sorted(strlist, key=lambda name: (re.findall(regex,name)[0][i] for i in key))
```

Also tried (w/o success):

```
for i in key:
  strlist.sort(key=lambda name: re.findall(regex,name)[0][key[i]])
```

Expected result:

```
['synopsys_SS_1v_-40c_SS.lib', 'synopsys_TT_1v_-40c_TT.lib', 'synopsys_SS_2v_-40c_SS.lib', 'synopsys_SS_2v_-40c_TT.lib', 'synopsys_FF_3v_-40c_FF.lib', 'synopsys_TT_4v_125c_TT.lib']
```

Am I on the wrong track completely?  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you having trouble splitting the strings or sorting the resultant list?

Comment: And can you show a sample of the desired output?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: I'm not having trouble splitting, just sorting by a given set of keys.  This is not a homework question, it's part of code I'm writing for work.

Comment: Added expected results

Comment: Could you please post the the list produced by ```re.findall(regex,name)```?

Comment: Your first attempt with `for i in key` was almost right, however the expression you used returns a generator. For a sorting key you want to use a `tuple` instead. So by using `lambda name: tuple(... for i in key)` it should work.

Comment: @a_guest That worked. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to @a_guest for providing the missing piece of the puzzle.  Here's the working solution:

```
fids_single = sorted(strlist, key=lambda name: tuple(re.findall(regex,name)[0][i] for i in key))
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a key function that will return the relevent portions of each string, in order of precedence, and use that function for the sort key.

```
one = ["synopsys_SS_2v_-40c_SS.lib","synopsys_SS_1v_-40c_SS.lib",
       "synopsys_SS_2v_-40c_TT.lib","synopsys_FF_3v_-40c_FF.lib",
       "synopsys_TT_4v_125c_TT.lib", "synopsys_TT_1v_-40c_TT.lib"]    

expected = ['synopsys_SS_1v_-40c_SS.lib', 'synopsys_TT_1v_-40c_TT.lib',
            'synopsys_SS_2v_-40c_SS.lib', 'synopsys_SS_2v_-40c_TT.lib',
            'synopsys_FF_3v_-40c_FF.lib', 'synopsys_TT_4v_125c_TT.lib']
```

Using your regular expression to split the string;

```
import operator, re
pattern = r'.*(FF|TT|SS)_([-\.\d]+v)_([-\.\d]+c)_(FF|TT|SS).*'
rx = re.compile(pattern)
seq = [2,1,3]
def key(item, seq = seq):
    seq = operator.itemgetter(*seq)
    a, b, c, d = rx.findall(item)
    return seq([a, b, c, d])


one.sort(key = key)
assert one == expected
```

---

The key function can be written without using a regular expression which may make it a bit less complicated.

```
def key(item, seq = seq):
    seq = operator.itemgetter(*seq)
    _, a, b, c, d = item.split('_')
    d, _ = d.split('.')
    print a, b, c, d
    return seq([a, b, c, d])
```

You may want to use names that are more descriptive than `a, b, c, d`.  It relies on the strings having the same *pattern*.

Comment: @Kidneys Your first attempt with `for i in key` was almost right, however the expression you used returns a generator. For a sorting key you want to use a `tuple` instead. So by using `lambda name: tuple(... for i in key)` it should work.